# Tax showing twice in cart and invoice etc but calculating correctly

Tags: magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.3.1

Tax is calculated correctly but it is showing twice in shopping cart and invoices. See an example in the below image GST and Tax is shown which is the same (10% GST).

How can I show just one, preferably GST?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

login in Magento admin section and navigate to

store -> configration -> sales -> Tax

Click on shopping cart display settings and make sure you have No for Display Full Tax Summary. If it is yes make it No.

After change configuration Clear cache.

Please find attachment [image]

Comment: Thanks! I did try this but may not have cleared the cache the first time.